# WPF XAML combobox synchronized with the actual value upon updated ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I'm having a problem with keeping my combobox synchronized with the actual selected value. I have a data-grid which I bind the selected row values to an object. The selected object has a property code with value "test2".

My combobox has an option "test1" and "test2" and "test3"

When I select this object, the combobox update with the correct value "test2", but on update of the ItemsSource it automaticaly sets the first alternative in the combobox due my use of isSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true. My application poll new items every 10 sec and update/refresh the itemssource, my question is then how can I make the combobox be synchronized with the actual chosen combobox alternative/item?

Like if I choose "test3" and the itemssource updates, the combobox will still show "test3" and not "test1" the first default. Or rather if I haven't chosen another value, it would still stay unchanged with the current value from the selected object "test"?

Here is my XAML code: The object I'm binding to is a public UserObject Object.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Object.Code, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="4 4 0 4" FontSize="13" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValue = "{Binding Object.Code}"  SelectedValuePath="Code" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCode}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  />
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
private void RefreshFunc()
    {
        string objectCode = Object.Code;

        //update/refresh the itemssource
        ToRefreshItemsSource();

        Object.Code = objectCode;
    }
```